# Node.js REST API deploy to cloud server

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I have developed a Node.js REST API. When I upload it to cloud server then the API is accessible by HTTP but not by HTTPS. When sending requests to my website the API shows an error called (failed). I use Apache on my server. So now what can I do now for making live this API?

Comment: check error logs in apache

Comment: it looks like a problem with your SSL certificate, I would recommend you to push your API on heroku and test it there.